# What is an R function for filling NA with specific string values?

Tags: r, if-statement, na

I am working with the IMDB dataset and am trying to find the best solution for filling in my empty values, an example is below,
Example:

```
showTitle        genres
Money Heist      Action,Crime,Mystery
The Office       Comedy
Money Heist      NA
Breaking Bad     Crime,Drama,Thriller
Money Heist      Action,Crime,Mystery
Money Heist      NA
The Office       NA
```

Desired Result

```
showTitle        genres
    Money Heist      Action,Crime,Mystery
    The Office       Comedy
    Money Heist      Action,Crime,Mystery
    Breaking Bad     Crime,Drama,Thriller
    Money Heist      Action,Crime,Mystery
    Money Heist      Action,Crime,Mystery
    The Office       NA
```

attempted

```
df %>% if(df$showTitle == "Money Heist"){df$genres} <- Action,Crime,Mystery
```

If the solution is possible without an If statement thats fine as long as it isnt manually correcting the cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer was given by @DPH, I am not sure why he deleted.

You can use `tidyr::fill` to replace `NA` values for each `showTitle`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(showTitle) %>%
  fill(genre, .direction = 'updown') %>%
  ungroup

#  showTitle    genre               
#  <chr>        <chr>               
#1 Money Heist  Action,Crime,Mystery
#2 Money Heist  Action,Crime,Mystery
#3 Breaking Bad Crime,Drama,Thriller
#4 Money Heist  Action,Crime,Mystery
#5 Money Heist  Action,Crime,Mystery
#6 The Office   Comedy              
#7 The Office   Comedy
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the details provided, perhaps this type of approach would suit:

```r
library(tidyverse)
# Create some 'fake' data
df <- data.frame(primaryTitle = c("Money Heist", "Money Heist", "Die Hard", "Die Hard", "Die Hard"),
                 genre = c("Action,Crime,Mystery", NA, "Action", "Action", NA))
df
#>   primaryTitle                genre
#> 1  Money Heist Action,Crime,Mystery
#> 2  Money Heist                 <NA>
#> 3     Die Hard               Action
#> 4     Die Hard               Action
#> 5     Die Hard                 <NA>

# Take the fake data
df %>%
  # sort the data by title
  arrange(primaryTitle) %>%
  # if the genre is "NA" and the title == the previous title,
  # fill in genre with the previous genre
  mutate(genre = if_else(is.na(genre) & primaryTitle == lag(primaryTitle),
                        lag(genre),
                        genre))
#>   primaryTitle                genre
#> 1     Die Hard               Action
#> 2     Die Hard               Action
#> 3     Die Hard               Action
#> 4  Money Heist Action,Crime,Mystery
#> 5  Money Heist Action,Crime,Mystery
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

With your example:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~showTitle, ~genre,
  "Money Heist",      "Action,Crime,Mystery",
  "Money Heist",      NA,
  "Breaking Bad",     "Crime,Drama,Thriller",
  "Money Heist",      "Action,Crime,Mystery",
  "Money Heist",      NA,
  "The Office",       NA
)


df
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>   showTitle    genre               
#>   <chr>        <chr>               
#> 1 Money Heist  Action,Crime,Mystery
#> 2 Money Heist  <NA>                
#> 3 Breaking Bad Crime,Drama,Thriller
#> 4 Money Heist  Action,Crime,Mystery
#> 5 Money Heist  <NA>                
#> 6 The Office   <NA>

df %>%
  arrange(showTitle) %>%
  mutate(genre = if_else(is.na(genre) & showTitle == lag(showTitle),
                        lag(genre),
                        genre))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>   showTitle    genre               
#>   <chr>        <chr>               
#> 1 Breaking Bad Crime,Drama,Thriller
#> 2 Money Heist  Action,Crime,Mystery
#> 3 Money Heist  Action,Crime,Mystery
#> 4 Money Heist  Action,Crime,Mystery
#> 5 Money Heist  Action,Crime,Mystery
#> 6 The Office   <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

One liner with base and indexing the subset through `which()`,

```
df[which(df$showTitle == 'Money Heist' & is.na(df$genre)), 'genre'] <- "Action,Crime,Mystery"
     showTitle                  genre
1  Money Heist   Action,Crime,Mystery
2  Money Heist   Action,Crime,Mystery
3  Breaking Bad  Crime,Drama,Thriller
4  Money Heist   Action,Crime,Mystery
5  Money Heist   Action,Crime,Mystery
6  The Office    <NA>
```